# Get data after second underscore from back in python dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to get data after second underscore from back in python dataframe?

```
    number
0   a_bc_def 12_23_this_6729
1   abc_def,122$3_this_6729
2   abc_def_1_2_23_this_6729


    number
0   this_6729
1   this_6729
2   this_6729
```

I tried to get data from second underscore from beginning.

```
df['number'] = df['number'].str.split('_',2).apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

How to do that from second underscore from back ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for apply, this can be done with `str` method operations

`str.split('_')` to split on underscores

`str[-2:]` to select the last 2 elements post-split

`str.join('_')` to join those elements into a single string

```
df['number']=df['number'].str.split('_').str[-2:].str.join('_')

0    this_6729
1    this_6729
2    this_6729
```

Comment: Do we get any improvement by avoiding apply? There is no vectorization here right?

Comment: It looks like on the test data repeated to make a 130k row dataframe, the apply answer provided by sam was actually slightly faster, `28.2 ms` vs `35.8 ms` for my answer

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to reverse the string for the same, do the operation, and reverse again.

```
df['number'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[::-1].split('_',2)[-1][::-1])
```

It's not very efficient since you need to reverse twice, but of strings are not too long this will not be that bad in my opinion.